# After installation Sitecore 9.2 with SXA not able to create JSS Tenant and site

Tags: sxa, jss

I have installed Sitecore 9.2 with supported SXA on my local environment, but not able to create JSS Tenant as describe in Sitecore help document. When we logged-in sitecore I can see the only Tenant instead of the JSS Tenant.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the JSS Server Package as well? I think it is mandatory to be able to create JSS tenants and sites.

Comment: Make sure that you have the following path `/sitecore/templates/Branches/Foundation/JSS Experience Accelerator`, `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/JSS Experience Accelerator` and `/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/JSS SXA`. Those are available when you install the SXA module 1.9. Note that the installation steps should be as follows: 1. Install Sitecore Powershell. 2. Install Sitecore SXA 1.9. 3. Install JavaScript Services 12

Comment: Thanks, @Jean-FrançoisL'Heureux

Answer (score 1):

Soln: **Sitecore JavaScript Services Server for Sitecore 9.2 XP 12.0.0 rev. 190522** is required to install for the above porblem.
[image]